# Divs aligned to left and center on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to layout a page to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LLqwX/1/

But I cannot figure out how to get the divs "logo" and "sometext" to be on the same line as the buttons. I would like it all to stay as it is, with the same colors everywhere, just that the top two lines would become friends and want to stay on the same line together.

### HTML

```html
<div id="top">
    <div id="logo">logo</div>
    <div id="sometext">text text</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#">btn 1</a>
        <a href="#">btn 2</a>
        <a href="#">btn 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="hello">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#top {
    background: #ccc;
}
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ff00ff;
}
#sometext {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffff00;
}
#menu {
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    background: #444;
}
#hello {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #888
}
```

Comment: The rule that you must have code when posting a link to jsfiddle is there for a reason.  Please do not circumvent it by formatting random text in your question as code.  Include the code.

Comment: Sorry. Just felt clearer to show the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `display: inline-block` to the `#menu`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LLqwX/3/

Comment: I would like the buttons to be centered on the page. Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same `inline-block` method you've used elsewhere:

```css
#menu {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLqwX/2/

**EDIT:**

I realize that you probably want the buttons to remain centered.
There are many methods of structuring this, but I tried to minimize changes to your original code.

```html
<div id="headleft">
    <div id="logo">logo</div>
    <div id="sometext">text text</div>
</div>
```

```css
div#headleft {
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLqwX/4/

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to keep the buttons centered is to use a flex layout.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fred02138/LLqwX/6/) showing how.

CSS

```
#top {
    background: #ccc;
    display: flex;
}
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ff00ff;
}
#sometext {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffff00;
}
#menu {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
}

#content {
    background: #444;
}
#hello {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #888
}
```